# Can we create B2B eCommerce Website using SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one requirement, to create a B2B eCommerce Website. I was thinking to check the possibilities with SharePoint Online. Or if anyone can recommend any other software.
I heard about magento is best for B2B eCommerce Site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create eCommerce B2b website with SharePoint but you need to have SharePoint skills to actually work on that.There is no out of box template in SharePoint for this

I think if you need to create eCommerce website, Magneto is best option as you will get out of the box templates with which you can start working on. Some of  other  features of Magneto are

1. Magento B2B e-commerce includes all that you need for your online store – you can offer multiple brands through channel partners and key accounts, and seamlessly manage all your accounts
2. With Magento B2B e-commerce, you can carry out customer segmentation and tailor experiences to specific groups of companies or individuals based on their browsing behavior or purchase history.
3. Since B2B selling involves bulk orders at regular intervals, Magento offers a robust quotation system that allows buyers to request a quote.

You can then integrate SharePoint and your eCommerce platform to get more insight about your eCommerce website.

Example: *Microsoft SharePoint has tools that allow the gathering of actionable business intelligence which gets better insight into the performance of your business and into what you might do to improve it.*

Other platform you can use is Shopify , Wix, Volusion

Comment: Thanks for reply Amit, We have drooped the plan to use SharePoint. we are creating that using Magento.